# Python Sudoku: How can I implement a for loop subgrid?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement a function that gets a nested list of Sudoku and returns True if valid and False otherwise. I implemented row checking and column checking, but subgrid checking is not working.

```
GRID_SIZE = 9 
SUBGRID_SIZE = 3

def check_grid_if_valid(grid):
    
    gridlist = []
    for i in range(GRID_SIZE):
        # column
        for j in range(GRID_SIZE):
            if grid[j][i] in gridlist and grid[j][i] != None:
                return False
            gridlist.append(grid[j][i])
        gridlist.clear()
        # row        
        for j in range(GRID_SIZE):    
            if grid[i][j] in gridlist and grid[i][j] != None:
                return False
            gridlist.append(grid[i][j]) 
        gridlist.clear()
       
    # it is working now
    # subgrid
    for row in range(0, GRID_SIZE, SUBGRID_SIZE):
        for column in range(0, GRID_SIZE, SUBGRID_SIZE):
            for i in range(row, row + SUBGRID_SIZE):
                for j in range(column, column + SUBGRID_SIZE):
                    if grid[i][j] in gridlist and grid [i][j] != None:
                        return False
                    gridlist.append(grid[i][j])
            gridlist.clear()
     
      
    return True
```

Thanks to @OneCricketeer for kind help!

Comment: Hint: If you loop range(3), then `grid[i][j]` will be only get you the top left subgrid, assuming 0,0 is the top left coordinate... How are you planning on checking other subgrids?

Comment: Do you mean I need range(3,6) and range(6,9) also...?

Comment: Yes, or `range(start, start+SUBGRID_SIZE)`. You can also replace `in [k for k in range(1,10)]` with `1 <=  grid[i][j] < 10`

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you need 9 total loops, so you cannot simply copy the two ranges to be the same. Think about "for all subgrids, loop over all rows and columns", thus giving at least three nested loops

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got the logic, although not everything. I'm updating the code.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
for subgrid_col in range(GRID_SIZE, step=SUBGRID_SIZE):
    for subgrid_row in range(GRID_SIZE, step=SUBGRID_SIZE):
        print(f"Checking subgrid ({subgrid_col}, {subgrid_row})") 
        for i in range(SUBGRID_SIZE):
            for j in range(SUBGRID_SIZE):
               num = grid[subgrid_col+i][subgrid_row+j]
```

Also, I'd suggest adding numbers simply into a set rather than a list, then checking the length of the set is 10 after adding all the numbers rather than checking containment while adding the numbers. You also shouldn't need to check `in range(1,10)` if you are limiting user-input elsewhere; this check would only be necessary if you're reading grids from external sources that don't limit your input